# With Delta update in Core API, what cursor do I pass in if I receive "has_more"

Tags: dropbox-api

When using the /delta endpoint with Core API and I receive a "has_more" response, what cursor should I pass into the following call to the endpoint?  Should I pass my newly received cursor, or the original cursor that I started the request with?

I presume the new response, but I've been unable to craft a request that actually gives me the has_more as part of the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the newly-received cursor.

Getting this response for testing should be pretty easy... just make sure you have a few thousand files.

Comment: Perfect.   Thanks for quick reply :).

I figured it'd be much easier to ask rather than creating thousands of files.  Plus now others know :)